# Dynamically add element and attribute of a XML in C#

Tags: xml

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
   <Index ID="1">
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <EmpID>12345</EmpID>
      <Department>OPS</Department>
   </Index>
</Employees>
```

I want to keep on adding the attributs like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
   <Index ID="1">
      <Name>XYZ</Name>
      <EmpID>12345</EmpID>
      <Department>OPS</Department>
   </Index>
   <Index ID="2">
      <Name>CFR</Name>
      <EmpID>3456</EmpID>
      <Department>IT</Department>
   </Index>
   <Index ID="3">
      <Name>VGT</Name>
      <EmpID>87654</EmpID>
      <Department>RFX</Department>
   </Index>
</Employees>
```

I would use this for a database, the through LINQ I need to fetch data as required

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample to get you started using linq to xml(in c#)

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Load("XMLFile1.xml");

XElement index2 = new XElement("Index");
index2.SetAttributeValue("ID", 2);

xDoc.Element("Employees").Add(index2);
```

This will give you the following xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Employees>
  <Index ID="1">
    <Name>XYZ</Name>
    <EmpID>12345</EmpID>
    <Department>OPS</Department>
  </Index>
  <Index ID="2" />
</Employees>
```

---

You can use the exact same process to fill your `index` tags as needed.

Comment: i had tried this, its working. But considering Index is a element it should have </Index> then only my XMl will be valid.